# Does Chain of Responsibility work here?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, strategy-pattern, chain-of-responsibility

I am designing a solution to a problem where I have list of items which have a score. For eg.

```
Product    Score
   A       10.4
   B       7.4
   Z       5.4
   D       4.4
   C       4.2
   H       4.1
   G       3.4
   BN      32.41
   CV      2.3
   AV      1.6
   FG      10.7
   .
   .
   .
   .
   ........
```

These items has to go through set of black box kinda steps..

scored item ----> Step 1 -- (re rank)---> Step 2 --(re rank)----> Step 3 -(re rank)---> Final Result

Each Step will rerank the some products based on their type. For eg. Step 1 will make sure Electronic products land in the top 10 score (it will make top 3 of electronic product fixed in top 10) when step 2 get this list it has to rerank but shouldn't re arrange the products fixed by step 1 but it should consider it while ranking others. I am thinking Chain of Responsibility design pattern. What do u guys think ?

Comment: Given that by your description, the order of ranking matters to some extent, I think CoR is definitely appropriate. It will make it easy to add more steps in the future.

Comment: I think design patterns are best used as recipes for dealing with specific object oriented problems within proposed (or existing) design.  Since you're still exploring the problem space, I wouldn't worry too much about this or that design pattern until I actually had a clear understanding of how I want to solve the problem. Patterns can help you create better solutions, but you have to make a first pass (or two or five) before locking yourself into any given pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chain Of Responsability](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/ChainOfResponsibility/) can be used.
Implement ConcreteHandler for each step. Define a chain via setSuccesor(...) method for each Handler.